# Which punctuation mark should be used here?

Tags: punctuation

> With those two possible values **:** 0 and 1, for each of the seven bits,
>   there is a total of 128 characters that can be used in the ASCII
>   encoding scheme.

What punctuation mark should the ":" be replaced by in the given sentence?

I could probably use a comma, but then it will result in too many commas in the sentence. Is there a way to replace the comma with some other punctuation mark? Will the sentence be correct if I don't use a punctuation mark (at the given place) at all?

Answer (score 1):

> **Your version**
>
> With those two possible values : 0 and 1, for each of
>   the seven bits, there is a total of 128 characters that can be used in
>   the ASCII encoding scheme.

The first thing to note is that a colon (and other such punctuation in English) should come directly after the previous word without a space.

I think you have a number of possibilities, e.g.

**1. semicolons**

*This option temporarily removed while I research my use of semi-colons*

---

**2. em dashes**

With those two possible values — 0 and 1, for each of the seven bits — there is a total of 128 characters that can be used in the ASCII encoding scheme.

> Em dashes set apart parenthetical phrases or clauses in a sentence. In
>   this use, em dashes are similar to commas and parentheses, but there
>   are subtle differences. For example, em dashes are used when a
>   parenthetical remark contains an internal comma or would otherwise
>   sound awkward if enclosed by commas.
>
> [Grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/grammar/emdash/)

---

**3. parentheses**

With those two possible values (0 and 1, for each of the seven bits) there is a total of 128 characters that can be used in the ASCII encoding scheme.

---

**Summary**

I would say it is a matter of weighing style and clarity. In this case I'd go for clarity and speaking personally would choose 3.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted. I disagree with option 1--I don't believe semicolons are normally used that way. In option 2, I think you should use em dashes rather than hyphens (or at least say they should be em dashes, if your keyboard doesn't allow for typing them out). While option 3 is technically correct, I believe using parentheses reduces the importance of the two numbers to a level lower than warranted. I think it should be "With those two values, 0 and 1 for the seven bits,..." or this same structure but with em dashes. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I don't think "0 and 1 for each of the seven bits" needs internal punctuation, but the entire phrase can be enclosed in commas or em dashes or parentheses.

Comment: I'll find out how to change to em dashes and alter them.

Comment: @Tragicomic - Having written it out without the internal comma as you suggest, I don't think it works. I'll return later and add a note to my answer saying why.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my feedback. I've removed my downvote.